# Mule Foreach's counter is null after Scatter Gather

Tags: mule

I have a Mule flow where I configured a Scatter Gather scope like below:

```
<flow name="simpleScatterGather">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/scatter-gather-test" doc:name="HTTP" />
    <scatter-gather doc:name="Scatter-Gather">
        <flow-ref name="subFlow1" doc:name="callSubFlow1"/>
        <flow-ref name="subFlow2" doc:name="callSubFlow2"/>
    </scatter-gather>
    <logger message="Payload is #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="logPayload"/>
    <foreach  doc:name="forEach">
        <logger message="Payload #[flowVars.counter] is : #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="logEachPayload"/>
    </foreach>
    <set-payload value="{&quot;message&quot;: &quot;success&quot;}" mimeType="application/json" doc:name="setResponse"/>
</flow>

<sub-flow name="subFlow1">
    <set-payload value="Payload1" doc:name="setPayload" />
</sub-flow>

<sub-flow name="subFlow2">
    <set-payload value="Payload2" doc:name="setPayload" />
</sub-flow>
```

The logger after Scatter Gather logs like below.

```
Payload is [Payload1, Payload2]
```

So it is clear that the above payload is a list.

The two loggers inside foreach logs like below.

```
Payload null is : Payload1
Payload null is : Payload2
```

So it means the MEL expression `#[flowVars.counter]` in the logger inside foreach returns null.

When I changed the foreach scope to include `collection` attribute explicitly like below:

```
<foreach  doc:name="forEach" collection="#[payload]">
    <logger message="Payload #[flowVars.counter] is : #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="logEachPayload"/>
</foreach>
```

the two loggers inside foreach logs like below.

```
Payload 1 is : Payload1
Payload 2 is : Payload2
```

Now the MEL expression `#[flowVars.counter]` works as expected

Can anyone please solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Why Im not exactly sure yet, but the scatter-gather returns a org.mule.DefaultMessageCollection which seems to mess the counter. However if you explicitly set the `collection` to `payload`, then it works.

```
<foreach doc:name="forEach" collection="#[payload]">
    <logger message="Payload #[flowVars.counter] is : #[payload]"
        level="INFO" doc:name="logEachPayload" />
</foreach>
```

Comment: Yes, it look likes a bug. I created a bug at (https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-9136)